# how set to data block property pallet in oracle forms to save data to table in oracle forms

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have two data blocks with two tables(with fields on forms).
How to save records of one table(column values of table one) to second table by setting property pallet.
I have tried by giving where conditions in data block 2 property pallet but it is not saving records to table two

Answer (score 1):

> by setting property pallet

Looks like you want to use the 1st block's values in the 2nd block. To do that - using the Property Palette - navigate to any block 2 item and check **Data** set of properties, especially

- copy value from item
- synchronize with item

When you're on that particular property, press `F1` on the keyboard to read what they do, and then pick the one you find the most appropriate.

You'll have to set that property for every block 2 item, of course - one by one.

Comment: i don't want to use the 1st block's values in the 2nd block rather i want to insert  records from data block1 table to data block2 table.

Comment: I want to insert records with data block instead of using insert into statement atleast is it possible to do so?

Comment: I don't think that you can avoid INSERT INTO in that case. You have to "take" data from somewhere (that's block 1's underlying table) and "put" those rows somewhere else (that's block 2's table), so that's classic INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM. How would you do that "automagically", just by having two blocks in the same form and using their property palettes? As far as I can tell, that won't work. What you could do is to create a **button** and its WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED trigger which does what I already described (INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM).

Comment: Ok Thank you  and one more doubt is there any possibility to ignore data block when we run a form(I have added debug messages to check but none of the messages are appearing )

Comment: What do you mean by "ignore data block"? Could you describe it?

Comment: I have a data block with two fields on form when i tried to  get record values(already set property pallet) it is not giving any data. also added some debug messages in some triggers to check but no messages

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you mean. Perhaps you should attach a screenshot which describes the problem. Anyway: if you want to **fetch** data from the database (into that data block), you should use built-in capabilities (i.e. enter query / execute query) and not do it manually.